# switch back and forth between TWO applications in Mac OS X

Tags: macos, mac

I am new to the mac and one of the biggest reasons I purchased one is because I anticipate that it will help increase productivity.

One way I hope to make this happen is to more easily switch back and forth between applications. For example if you are editing a web page you can switch back and forth between Textmate and Safari...

The ideal way to do this would probably be a gesture or a real simple keyboard shortcut. Is this something that can be customized? Is it already a feature of Mac Osx?

How do you switch back and forth between two applications?

Thanks.

Comment: ... This isnt really a programming question. Perhaps you intend to ask this on some other site?

Comment: You want http://apple.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I believe you're looking for Command-Tab

Comment: But it can help many folks program, or just many folks in general.

Comment: @Mike that may be true, but it's still off-topic here.

Comment: sorry, didn't know about the other forum. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Command+Tab

Similar to alt-tab in Windows.

Comment: It works even better than alt-tab on Windows (unless things have been improved since XP, which wouldn't surprise me), since the applications are kept in the order of most recently visited, so you can switch back and forwards between two applications with just one command-tab each time.

Comment: In addition: Use Shift + Command + Tab to scroll backwards.

Comment: Also, while holding tab, you can use your mouse to click on the app you want, or Esc to cancel out of switcher mode.